# Python Turtle not filling as per documentation example

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to show my daughter some code and thought turtle would be fun. I'm more of a numbers guy, but that's not much fun for kids.

I'm having trouble reproducing the documentation example. This is more just bothering me because I can't figure it out. There's lots of other stuff we can do.

The documentation example (copied below) is supposed to produce this picture. [image: Star 1]

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

That example won't run, but I modify the imports and calls slightly to allow it run. However, the fill doesn't work the same way. It fills in the entire shape - not leaving those gaps. This is more what I'd expect from the fill documentation about polygon start and end. But, any ideas?

```
from turtle import *

win = Screen()
t = Turtle()
t.color('red', 'yellow')
t.speed(0)
t.begin_fill()
while True:
    t.forward(200)
    t.left(170)
    if abs(t.pos()) < 1:
        break
t.end_fill()
win.exitonclick()
```

[image: My star]

Comment: Running your code I get the "supposed to produce" you list first with the gaps.

Comment: Oh, gosh...even worse than I expected. :-/

Python 2 or 3?

Comment: What you're seeing is the difference between the two common fill rules for self-intersecting polygons - "even-odd" in the first image, "nonzero winding number" in the second.  I suspect the two images came from different platforms, whose native graphic systems use a different rule.  (Data point: I get the even-odd version on my Mac.)

Comment: Mine is Python 3.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: That is fascinating, jasonharper. I just went spelunking in turtle and tkinter methods to see if I could unearth anyway to switch it, but couldn't find anything. 

I'm on Windows 3.7, DaveStSomeWhere - and apparently using the "nonzero winding number" method.