# Python Turtle transparent fill?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to recreate this picture using the Turtle library:

[image]

but I'm struggling when trying to make the inner circles 'transparent'.
I searched the documentation but found no way to change the opacity of the circle's fill color.

What I tried was:

```
colors = ["black", "magenta", "pink", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "white"]

for i in range(8):
    my_turtle.fillcolor(colors[i])
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(150)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    my_turtle.fillcolor("white")
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(130)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    my_turtle.fillcolor(colors[i])
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(100)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    my_turtle.fillcolor("white")
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(80)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    my_turtle.rt(45)
```

But what I got was:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `.fillcolor("")` on the inner circle would make it transparent - but this would just show the color of the outer circle, it wouldn't punch a hole in the outer circle like you need.  The only way I can think of to do this with `turtle` is to convert the circles to polygons, and draw both the inner and outer boundaries as part of the same `.begin_fill()` - with one of the boundaries in the opposite direction (clockwise vs. counterclockwise) to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse every smaller circle of the circle colors:

```
colors = ["black", "magenta", "pink", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "white"]

for i in range(8):
    my_turtle.fillcolor(colors[i])
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(150)
    my_turtle.circle(130, -360)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    my_turtle.fillcolor(colors[i])
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(100)
    my_turtle.circle(80, -360)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    my_turtle.rt(45)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may not need to add *negative signs* as @AnnZen suggests, but rather *comment characters*.  Your code, with the following lines removed, works fine for me:

```
for i in range(8):
    my_turtle.fillcolor(colors[i])
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(150)
    # my_turtle.end_fill()
    # my_turtle.fillcolor("white")
    # my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(130)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    # my_turtle.fillcolor(colors[i])
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(100)
    # my_turtle.end_fill()
    # my_turtle.fillcolor("white")
    # my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.circle(80)
    my_turtle.end_fill()
    my_turtle.rt(45)
```

A complete solution:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ['black', 'magenta', 'pink', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.width(6)

for color in COLORS:
    turtle.fillcolor(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(145)
    turtle.circle(130)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(115)
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.right(45)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

> The negative signs in Ann Zen's solution make each ring a polygon that
> touches itself at one point, but never overlaps itself. Your solution
> produces self-overlapping polygons, which have different results based
> on the polygon fill rule being used ("even-odd" vs. "nonzero winding
> number").

Yes, we've seen this before, usually with filled five-pointed stars.  Let's push @AnnZen's negative extent solution even further, drawing an entire double arc before filling it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ['black', 'magenta', 'pink', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.width(6)

for color in COLORS:
    turtle.fillcolor(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(145)
    turtle.circle(130, -360)
    turtle.circle(115)
    turtle.circle(100, -360)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.right(45)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Is this well behaved winding-number-wise?

Comment: I don't think this is going to work right on all platforms.  The negative signs in Ann Zen's solution make each ring a polygon that touches itself at one point, but never overlaps itself.  Your solution produces self-overlapping polygons, which have different results based on the polygon fill rule being used ("even-odd" vs. "nonzero winding number").  And the polygon fill rule is determined by the underlying platform's graphics system, rather than anything guaranteed by Tkinter.

Comment: Example of the fill rule difference I'm talking about at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032994/python-turtle-not-filling-as-per-documentation-example

Comment: @jasonharper, I understand and agree.  Someday I'll have a Windows Python turtle running just to check these inconsistencies.  Has anyone confirmed this one fails?